# HTTP proxy with zimbra zcs

Tags: proxy, zimbra

Does anyone know how I can enable HTTP / HTTPS proxy for domain in Zimbra. When I login to a secondary Zimbra domain it load the SSL cert for the primary domain.

Is there a way to set the zimbra proxy to also do HTTP / HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer to my own problem, the Zimbra wiki refers to a way to configure the nginx proxy to also handle HTTP/S. It has been a few days and I have not noticed any problems. The only catch was the instructions were for ZCS 6.0 and I running 7.1.1, so I am still on the look out for any problem.